# Как развернуть обученную ИИ модель для обработки данных?

Tags: python, нейронные-сети

Я новичок в питон и ИИ в целом
Обучил и сохранил модель в формате json и h5. Как теперь развернуть данную модель для обработки данных на основе полученных данных во время обучения?

Comment: Вас устроит такой ответ: "загрузите обученную модель в переменную `model` и воспользуйтесь методом `model.predict()`" ?  Если нет, то приведите в вопросе код в котором вы обучаете и сохраняете модель данных и небольшой пример входных данных. Также надо описать что вы пытаетесь сделать и что именно у вас не получается.

Comment: [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)